# MinGW Windows POSIX socket() не работает

Tags: windows, c, mingw, сокет

Windows XP, gcc version 3.4.5
gcc myprog.c -lwsock32

...

```
#ifdef WIN32  
#include <windows.h>
#endif
```

...

```
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
```

возвращает -1

Что делать ?

В Interix на той же машине работает (конечно без windows.h).

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо.
WSAStartup() помог
результат, конечно странноват == 1956

Ну, посмотрим, как будет дальше с fd_set

Comment: 1956 — маловато :).

Comment: @avp Если вы получили правильный ответ, его стоит принять, нажав на галку рядом с ответом.

Comment: Еще раз всем спасибо.
В первом приближении работает

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[WSAStartup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742213.aspx) / [WSACleanup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741549.aspx) есть?

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте посмотреть, что за ошибка с помощью [`WSAGetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741580.aspx).